# What is better from REST point of view,create dedicated endpoint or universal one for all API clients?

Tags: rest

We have an API and, for example, three clients call our API. Each of these clients need other fields from the same data. Should I create a dedicate endpoint for each one or return full data and client should take fields which or of interest to them?

For example, we have data like User with fields id, firstName, lastName, street, city, and first client needs only firstName, the second only lastName, and the third only city.

This is a simple example, but in reality, we have objects with 20-30 fields and each client needs only 3 fields.

Answer (score 1):

In REST (Representational state transfer) a path represents a resource, and *User* is a single resource, you do not have three different kinds of users, right?

So from a *REST* point of view you should only have one path to access a *User* object, but could add a query parameter to fill in only certain fields. This also would allow you for easier extension later - or not caring about the query parameter at all and always fill in all fields.

On the other hand if you don't care about the REST architectural style, you can do it however you like, but be prepared that the next dev will do it differently for some arbitrary reason, and the software tends to get harder to maintain.

Comment: This is the way to go. Very flexible, requires the least custom code, easily extensible. And you can even optimize your query layer to only retrieve the requested fields, if you so desire.

Answer (score -1):

I would provide a dedicated version for each client. The same method in the REST controller. The only difference will be a part of URL - the path variable. Like this:

```
http://my-service/{client}/user
```

You will only need to code the endpoint once and return a different DTOs (projections of the User entity) depending on PathVariable 'client'.